# Please help something so simple as using a greater than expression shouldn't be so difficult

Tags: reporting-services

I am very new to using Report Builder and am trying to use an expression to pull lock dates greater than **12/31/2012**.

The error:

> The Value expression for the query parameter ‘@lock_date’ contains an
>   error: [BC30201] Expression expected.

The query parameter:

```
=Fields!lock_date.Value>"12/31/2012 00:00:00"
```

Please help - something so simple as using a greater than expression shouldn't be so difficult.

Answer (score 2):

You don't use an expression in the query parameter; rather you use the parameter in your query expression. In this instance you would create a date parameter called `lock_date`. This will show a text box and date picker in your parameters that allows you to enter a date. You don't enter an expression here, just a date to use in other expressions.

Then you filter your data on this parameter, for example in your SQL for your dataset:

```
SELECT lock_date, somefield, anotherfield
FROM MyTable
WHERE lock_date > @lock_date
```

You could also create a filter expression in your table properties that uses the parameter.